# Сan't set up eslint "ignoreUrls" and "ignoreStrings"

Tags: angular, eslint, maxlength, eslintrc

Trying to use eslint + prettier with default angular project.

I want to turn off the warning of exceeding the length of url.

Here is my .eslintrc.json

```
{
  "files": ["*.html"],
  "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "max-len": [
      "warn",
      {
        "code": 120,
        "ignoreTemplateLiterals": true,
        "ignoreStrings": true,
        "ignoreUrls": true,
        "ignorePattern": "<path([/s/S]*?)/>"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But still got warnings "line length not allowed"

[html and warn example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8DBA.png)

Comment: Same here, did you find a solution?

Comment: nope unfortunately